# How does sunshine capture and stream the desktop

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, rtsp

I am looking to understand the [Sunshine project by Loki](https://github.com/loki-47-6F-64/sunshine) which works with [moonlight](https://moonlight-stream.org/) to stream a desktop with very low latency based on Nvidia's GameStream.

I looked at the source code on GitHub, but couldn't figure out how the screen is captured and the stream is converted to an RTSP packet.
I think they use ffmpeg to capture the screen.

I did find the RTSP packet definition [here](https://github.com/loki-47-6F-64/sunshine/blob/master/sunshine/rtsp.cpp)

Could someone explain how this works?
I am trying to understand this on a low level, since I want to implement a similar program as part of a project later(probably in C++ itself).

I don't have much experience here, but am looking to get my hands dirty! :)

Hope my question is clear and any help to understand this or other resources I could take a look at would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you understand? I can't understand it too. and I also want to find how it checks to pair with moonlight.@user16235056

Comment: Hey @Parisa.H.R I didn't understand it. I got engaged in another project and I will update here if I get it.

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this in searching for something else, so figured I'd answer since I am the new maintainer of the project.

On Windows we use the [DXGI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3ddxgi/desktop-dup-api) api, as of writing this answer.

The former Nvidia Gamestream service uses [NVFBC](https://developer.nvidia.com/capture-sdk) (Nvidia frame buffer capture) which is deprecated on Windows.

For Linux we also use NVFBC as well as a few other protocols depending on which desktop environment the user has.

The project is now available at https://github.com/LizardByte/Sunshine

If you'd like to chat with developers on the project, please reach out on our [discord](https://app.lizardbyte.dev/discord)